# "List of tasks" or "tasks' list"

Tags: phrases, nouns, possessives

Which of these forms is better: *list of tasks* or *tasks' list*? Another question is whether I should use an apostrophe or not (*tasks's list* vs *tasks list*).

Other phrases which are similar to this, but aren't quite what I'm looking for, are *list of projects* and *task's action* (one task this time).

Maybe the answer is obvious, but English is not my native language so I need to understand it.

Comment: This is also commonly called a 'to-do list'.

Comment: Not exactly. These "tasks" are some kind of items in my application. If I mention task list in documentation, I mean a list of these items.

Comment: Oops! Got it now.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The usual phrase is "task list" (without plural or apostrophe).

"List of tasks" is perfectly acceptable, and perhaps preferable in general writing; but in referring to a list (almost like a name for it) "task list" is overwhelmingly the common expression.

"Tasks' list" would be very unusual: the possessive 's and its variants are usually used only for real possession, not for more general relationships; and tend not to be used for abstract nouns, though this is not a firm prohibition.

Comment: Ok, so generally I use possesive 's in phrases like "person's belongings" or "Joe's umbrella" and ommit this in phrases like "project launch date" or "task duration".

Comment: Absolutely. All four of those examples work.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to add one suggestion to Colin's answer: preferably you'd use "task list" instead of "tasks list" form.

See the following thread for reference: [should a list of tokens be called a "token list" or a "tokens list"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/59059/should-a-list-of-tokens-be-called-a-token-list-or-a-tokens-list)

Comment: Your post doesn answer the question and reads more like a comment than an answer.