# should a list of tokens be called a "token list" or a "tokens list"

Tags: grammatical-number, lists, attributive-nouns

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“User accounts” or “users account?”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1314/user-accounts-or-users-account)

I ask because a list of tasks would usually be called a "task list". However a list or previous winners of a competition seems to be called a "winners list" rather than a "winner list".
Thanks.

Comment: If every individual item on said list is to consist of just one singular token (not two or more tokens) each, then "token list" would be most apt; otherwise, "tokens list" would be. Surrounding context in the former case shall differentiate intended meaning-construct from the more-standard adjectival meaning's usage of 'token'.

Answer (score 14):

In constructions like this you generally use the singular, although there are exceptions. Some of these exceptions may be attempts to avoid ambiguity (for example, a *sundry store* might be a store that is sundry, rather than a store that sells sundries; a *sundries store* is unambiguous). Other exceptions seem not to have a reason.

This is a perfect question for [Ngrams](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=token+list%2Ctokens+list&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3), and here is the answer:

[image: Ngram token(s) list]

So use the singular.

Comment: How does this account for the use of "token" as an adjective meaning "done for the sake of appearances or as a symbolic gesture"?

Comment: @Robusto: that question has nothing to do with this one, and if it's not easily answered by searching, you could ask it here as a new question.

Comment: I was making a comment on your NGram search. Part of your result has to include false positives that result from the usage I described.

Comment: @Robusto: I see. Checking the results shows that these usages are a very small percentage of the hits.

Comment: I think @Robusto's question is relevant here. *Sundry store* is ambiguous, *token list* is ambiguous for the same reason. However I would say "token list" anyway. Context is everything.

Comment: Possibly because people rarely have reason to refer to a list made for symbolic purposes. Maybe something like, "The secret police demanded he divulge the names of all other malcontents he knew, but he gave them only a token list of people they already knew about."

Comment: Or: "they had already decided who would get the job, but they needed to make a token list of candidates to interview."

Comment: How about *the entity's actions list*, is this correct?