# "Employee list" or "employees list"

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number, attributive-nouns

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [User’s Guide vs Users’ Guide](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/36657/users-guide-vs-users-guide)
>   [should a list of tokens be called a “token list” or a “tokens list”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/59059/should-a-list-of-tokens-be-called-a-token-list-or-a-tokens-list)

I know we can use *list of employees*, but I'd like to know which is preferred or more correct: *employee list* or *employees list*?

Comment: @WillHunting: I would never downvote because something is a duplicate, but I might downvote if a question seems to be about a trivial matter, while also showing no research effort. In other words, if the first three questions that pop into my head are: (1) Who cares? (2) Why would it matter? and (3) Why can't you figure this out? then I could see myself downvoting. When such questions are overrunning the board, I don't think it's a necessarily a bad thing for the community to show collective disdain. (Note: I didn't downvote this, but I'll bet it would fare better with some elaboration).

Comment: +1 from me for similar reasons. I find @J.R.'s reasons acceptable, if a little harsh, but I think downvoting with no justification serves no purpose other than deterring fresh users.

Comment: Oh, and a google search for this issue returns no adequate results.

Comment: @Nieszka: I didn't mean to sound "harsh," and I don't want to deter new users from joining, but I don't mind deterring new users from asking shallow, inane, easily-verifiable questions. Every try Yahoo! Answers? People can ask anything they want to there - _so they do_: everything from "What should I name my baby?" to "How do i tell this girl that i like her?" I think that setting a tone where shallow questions are sharply downvoted can create a culture whereby people are not so flippant about asking them, which can help the long-term health of the community as a whole.

Answer (score 4):

"Employee" here is a noun adjunct (a noun used as an adjective). Noun adjuncts tend to be single (raisin bread, rose bush, bike path, etc.) because adjectives in English don't have a number.

See examples and explanation here: http://www.englishcorner.vacau.com/grammar/rules/nounadj.html

So, Employee List would be standard.

Comment: Noun adjuncts are not really nouns used as adjectives, because they fail the predicate test for adjectives. You cannot say with *employee list*, that the list **is** an employee, whereas with an adjective, you can do so. Contrast *singing lessons* with a *singing man*. In the first case, it is a noun adjunct, not an adjective, because the lessons are not singing, but in the second case, it is a real adjective.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with *Employee List* (or *Employee Directory*). It is far more common to use the singular in this case. (You can Google both "Employee List" and "Employees List" to prove it to yourself.)