# plural nouns: should I add "s" ending to both nouns?

Tags: nouns, adjectives, grammatical-number, attributive-nouns

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“User accounts” or “users account”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1314/user-accounts-or-users-account)
>   [“BookList” or “booksList?”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/17329/booklist-or-bookslist)
>   [Is it correct to say “lesson count” or “lessons count”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/14115/is-it-correct-to-say-lesson-count-or-lessons-count) 
>   [should a list of tokens be called a “token list” or a “tokens list”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/59059/should-a-list-of-tokens-be-called-a-token-list-or-a-tokens-list)
>   [“Employee list” or “employees list”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/80040/employee-list-or-employees-list) 
>   ["Thing count" or "things count"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/79429/thing-count-or-things-count)
>   And others

I know I can say

> what color of towel do you like?

And the same:

> what towel color do you like?

I also know I can say the same about multiple colors:

> what colors of towels do you like?

But I'm not sure if I should say:

> what towels colors do you like?

or

> what towel colors do you like?