# Should it be for example "product prices" or "products prices"

Tags: grammar, nouns, grammatical-number

I don't know what are the correct terms for this question. Which form is correct for cases of multiple plural nouns, both should be plural or only the second one, for example:

> product prices

or

> product**s** prices

or even maybe:

> product**s'** prices

Comment: n-Tuplicate. Variants of this question have appeared on these pages earlier and suitably answered. Try checking previous posts. http://english.stackexchange.com/q/93378/14666 and all the others cited there as well.

Comment: This particular example may not be covered in previous threads. I'll just mention that (1) it's unusual (though not unknown where sensible: dogs home; working mens club) for plural nouns (especially hybrids like mens) to be chosen as attributives; (2) particular cases can be looked up on the internet.