# "Countries List" or "Country List"?

Tags: grammaticality, grammatical-number, attributive-nouns

> **Duplicate of:**
>   [“User accounts” or “users account”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1314/user-accounts-or-users-account)
>   [“Employee list” or “employees list”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/80040/employee-list-or-employees-list)
>   [Should a list of tokens be called a “token list” or a “tokens list”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/59059/should-a-list-of-tokens-be-called-a-token-list-or-a-tokens-list)
>   [“BookList” or “booksList?”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/17329/booklist-or-bookslist)
>   [Is it correct to say “lesson count” or “lessons count”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/14115/is-it-correct-to-say-lesson-count-or-lessons-count) 
>   ["Thing count" or "things count"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/79429/thing-count-or-things-count)
>   And others

Which of the following are correct?

> 1. Countries List
> 2. Country List

It is the title of a web page where users can view the list of countries and select one.

Comment: This may be different based on one's dialect, but for me (American speaker) only _Country List_ and _List of Countries_ are correct.

Comment: @BillFranke- Interestingly, if you add an adjective then *countries* becomes viable:  *banned countries list*, *first-world countries list*, etc. So then can you elide the adjective and get *countries list*?

Comment: @Jim good point, but then it *sounds* exactly like the possessive form, i.e. *countries' list*.

Comment: @tchrist - User's Guide / Users' Guide, in here Guide can be taken as a sigular ! so i am not sure how countries list could be similar to them

Bill thanks bro, it is an interesting share

Jim thanks mate, my notion here to use "Countries List" was to have a short title

Comment: @Jim: Yes, _Banned Countries List_ etc. is perfectly normal to me. One can do that elision thing with math, and with natural language in a piece of discourse, but not as a rule of thumb: No one will know where it came from, because elision isn't always detectable. I think that _Countries List_ may be normal British English, though.

Comment: @Bill Franke So usage of "Countries List" is also grammatically correct ?

Comment: Yes, it's grammatically correct. As I said, I suspect that it would be considered idiomatic British English. OTOH, it's just a list name, so grammar is a tertiary concern here. What's important is whether the reader will understand the meaning of the list name, and both "country list" and "countries list" are perfectly clear. It's a style choice.

Comment: _Countries list_ sounds very odd to my British ears. There are a lot of things that cannot be termed 'wrong' as in 'ungrammatical' but that are also never used except for quirky effect. _A desert ship_, _large and by_, _anchor was weighed_, _countries list_. I think even _country list_ would be tend to be avoided - is it a list of countries, or a list pertaining to the country being talked about (cf County Court)?

Comment: @Edwin it is just Country/countries list in the title, i would any day prefer list of countries. But in this scenario the rules are layed out and i have to follow any one of them to maintain consistency across other pages :) my doubt was on the grammer part thanks to you and Bill i am clear now

Answer (score 3):

Surely it's obvious that the list is a list. If this is a title and it needs to be as short as possible, then just head the page

> Countries

as that is a perfectly adequate description of the content. To add *List* is at best superfluous and at worst treating your users like idiots.

As such, this is not the same question as one about whether to use an apostrophe as in *Users/User's/Users' Guide* because for a book title you do need the word *Guide*. Even if "Countries" is a link with no visible content, it's unlikely to need *List*: it's likely to be more useful if it were worded "Choose a country".

Answer (score 1):

My gut feeling (British) says that a *list* always takes a singular form to qualify what kind of list it is, unless you use *list of ...*. My gut also insists that *list of countries* sounds more natural.

If you used a plural form then it'd also end up being somewhat easily confused with the possessive form - i.e. *the countries' list* or *the country's list*.

Comment: Yeah same here, i also feel that List of countries sound more natural but is usage of "Country List" correct ? Note: I have to keep the title as short as possible

Comment: I'd say it's grammatically correct, and if your goal is an extremely short title then go for it. At the very least it should cause less confusion when people read it out loud ;).