# Singular or Plural Before List?

Tags: grammatical-number, lists, titles

I'm trying to write a list of features available in my product, and I'm confused what the title should be:

Should I say "Features List" (features are plural) or "Feature List" (feature is singular).

Comment: You may also find other helpful answers in [this one](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/59059/should-a-list-of-tokens-be-called-a-token-list-or-a-tokens-list).

Comment: @KitFox: I don't think it's a duplicate, the rule of `<singular-noun> <plural-noun>` does not answer my question at all. However, the answer in the question in your comment does, so I think it would be better if you mark the one in your comment as the duplicate.

Comment: @KitFox, It doesn't appear duplicate to me. Tamer Shlash: "Feature List" appears correct to me, because it denotes a list of features, whereas "Features List" (if at all anyone used it), would tend to denote some sort of a list for each feature, wouldn't it?

Comment: @Pradyumna: I'm not a native English speaker, so I can't "taste" the language :)

Answer (score 8):

Either one is fine, but you can make it shorter by saying only "FEATURES". Readers will see that it's a list, so the word is superfluous.