# Thing table or things table?

Tags: grammatical-number

By table I mean that thing with rows and columns. How do I say correctly: "I'll add a record to the student table" or "I'll add a record to the students table"? Also what's right: "I'll add a record to the student list" or "I'll add a record to the students list"? What are grammar rules for these examples?

EDIT: Not the table that belongs to some student, table that contains information about students.

Comment: Generally, use the singular. But use the plural if the singular would be confusing.

Comment: Not the table that belongs to some student, table that contains information about students.

Comment: See also [Should a list of tokens be called a token list or a tokens list?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/59059/should-a-list-of-tokens-be-called-a-token-list-or-a-tokens-list?rq=1)